# Android Studio SQLCipher: Error resolving method 'loadLibs' in 'SQLiteDatabase'(SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs();)

Tags: android-studio, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

Error resolving method 'loadLibs' in 'SQLiteDatabase'(SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs();)

I am trying to use SQLCipher for android studio, although I have added library to dependencies I get this error.

(DBHelper class)

```
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_Path = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";

        Log.e("Path 1", DB_Path);

        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs();
        
    }
```

I have added this libraries:

```
implementation 'net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.4@aar'
implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.2.0'
```

(and also tried older library)

```
import net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase;
```

I have synced project, and built gradle, and tried "Invalidate caches" and Clean and Rebuild project, but problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

So after struggling with a similar issue for most of a day I think I have a solution...

My error started when I needed to migrate an app from using `net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.4.0` (Deprecated) to the listed replacement `net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.5` which then resulted in the app crashing on open with the exception `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(...`

All of the answers I was able to find only mention the need to have a call to `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs()` in the app but my app did not have that before this update and was working fine. Further the new library `net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.5` does not have any such method (I checked the source repo)... so after some more searching I found another method used in one of the test clases in the library source [(`net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher_cts.RoomUpsertTest`)](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android/blob/master/sqlcipher/src/androidTest/java/net/zetetic/database/sqlcipher_cts/RoomUpsertTest.java)

which is `System.loadLibrary("sqlcipher");`

So I added that into my DB initialisation and now the app runs fine again.